# Importing groovy files to another groovy file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a separate file named *stagUtils.groovy* with methods defined.

```
def init(def service, def type)
{
    return """
        stage ("Init") {
           //code
       }
"""
}
def Validate_MergeRequest(def type)
{
  return """
            stage('Validate MergeRequest') {
             //code
            }
"""
}
def Merge_Collision_Check()
{
    return """
            stage ('Merge Collision Check') {
              //code
            }
"""
}
```

I now want to use these method in my *jobdsl.groovy* file

```
//importing dependencies
import java.io.File
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import groovy.transform.Field

//template defnition
def pipelineTemplate(String type) {
 pipelineJob("${service}/${pipeline_name}-${type}-pipeline") {
        definition {
pipeline {
    agent any   
    stages {
         // I want to call init method here
        }
}
}
}
}
```

Many suggest to use shared-library in pipelines. But as I am executing using job dsl, here shared libraries are not supported.  I tried evaluate, but it was of no use. Help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sourceFile = readFileFromWorkspace("stagUtils.groovy")
Class stagUtils = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(sourceFile)

stagUtils.init()
```

or as documentation [says](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Real-World-Examples#import-other-files-ie-with-class-definitions-into-your-script)

add to stagUtils.groovy

```
package utils
```

and in  jobdsl.groovy

```
import utils.stagUtils

def myJob = job('example')
stagUtils.init()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, I use this syntax:

```
pipeline {
    agent any   
    stages {
         stage("Load groovy file") {
            pipeline = load 'stagUtils.groovy'
         }
         stage("Call function from groovy file") {
            pipeline.init()
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work in job dsl script?? Or is this just for pipelines??

Comment: It seems to me that it works in both cases. I used it in such a way that the different methods were in a separate groovy file. I always called them from other files in pipeline {} blocks.